# "Train data must be floating-point matrix," reading Matrix from YML File

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, svm

I am trying to read in a Mat of training data from a YML to pass to an SVM. I have written the matrix to a file with:

```
FileStorage fs("data.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "data" << data;
fs.release();
```

And in another method I read it in with:

```
FileStorage fs_train("data.yml", FileStorage::READ);
fs_train["data"] >> dataForSVM;
fs_train.release();
```

I then pass `dataForSVM` into the `SVM.train` method. If I skip the reading/writing portion, and simply pass the original `data` matrix to the SVM, everything is fine.

The additional step of reading the matrix in from a YML leads to the runtime error

> cv::Exception:
>   /tmp/opencv-pLxl/opencv-2.4.9/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:857:
>   error: (-5) train data must be floating-point matrix in function
>   cvCheckTrainData

Any advice?

Comment: Can you include your declarations of `data` and `dataForSVM`? I assume those types match?

Comment: @chmod_007 Both are declared the same, i.e. `Mat data;`